# How to make sure PC is disconnected when it sleeps (S3 sleep)

Tags: windows-10, sleep, connection

How can I make sure my PC stays disconnected when it sleeps? I want it to drop and reject all connections.

My firmware supports S3 sleep while S0 standby state is not available.

There's a hidden power option "Networking connectivity in standby" which can be set to "Disable networking in standby" but I remember reading it was for S0.

```
Powercfg -a

The following sleep states are available on this system:
    Standby (S3)

The following sleep states are not available on this system:
    Standby (S1)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.
    Standby (S2)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.
    Standby (S0 Low Power Idle)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.
```

Answer (score 1):

S3 sleep state is technically [more](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/system-sleeping-states) shut down than S0, but whether your network card is still enabled in each state-level is ultimately up to the device-specific drivers rather than windows.

You can try and manually [Disable Network Connectivity while in Modern Standby](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/146593-enable-disable-network-connectivity-modern-standby-windows-10-a.html) with powercfg:

```
# On battery (default is 2)
powercfg /setdcvalueindex scheme_current sub_none F15576E8-98B7-4186-B944-EAFA664402D9 0
# Plugged in (default is 1)
powercfg /setacvalueindex scheme_current sub_none F15576E8-98B7-4186-B944-EAFA664402D9 0
```

---

If you want to use the GUI, then you can try and enable the hidden "Network connectivity in Standby" mode with `powercfg` like:

```
# use +ATTRIB_HIDE to re-hide the option
powercfg -attributes F15576E8-98B7-4186-B944-EAFA664402D9 -ATTRIB_HIDE
```

Once that's done, [check your power options](https://www.top-password.com/blog/prevent-windows-10-from-disconnecting-network-during-sleep/) for the missing settings:

> Open the Power Options. Locate and expand the "Network connectivity in Standby" setting.

> Open the Settings app and navigate to System -> Power & sleep. On the right-side pane, click the option “When my PC is asleep and on battery power, disconnect from the network” and change it

Comment: Problem is that I don't think I have "Modern Standby", I'm using not-so-modern old school sleep state instead. I think modern standby corresponds to S0 which is not supported by my firmware.


Edit: My network card is realtek and I don't see an option to disconnect and reject connections when PC sleeps. There's an option to reduce speed to 10 mbps though.

Edit 2: On the link you shared it shows that S3 sleep state is NOT modern standby, so this setting might not prevent connections for me.